# Error when getting plist data after writing value to it

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, swift, exc-bad-instruction

I am trying to make a plist file to share data between my `SKScene` and settings view controller.
Since I allow the user to access the settings any time during the game, if the user made any changes, I always get data from the plist file b4 starting the game.

```
func startGame() {
    gameStarted = true;

    plistPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Settings", ofType: "plist");
    dict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: plistPath);

    let speed: CGFloat = dict.valueForKey("Speed") as CGFloat;

}
```

If the user does not go to the settings to change the settings at all, I can run this function with no interruptions and errors.
But once I change the speed value in the settings view controller, and once this function is called, `plistPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Settings", ofType: "plist");` always throws a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` error.

And this is how I change the value from the plist

```
let plistPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Settings", ofType: "plist");
var dict: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: plistPath);

dict = NSMutableDictionary(dict.setValue(speed, forKey: "Speed"));
dict.writeToFile(plistPath, atomically: true);
```

EDIT: I noticed the problem comes from this line `let speed: CGFloat = dict.valueForKey("Speed") as CGFloat;` It seems that once I remove it no errors are thrown, but its a I need it to read value from the plist?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
var plistPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Settings", ofType: "plist");
```

Instead of

```
let plistPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Settings", ofType: "plist");
```

this resolved my problem.